# jQuery Tooltip event not firing on dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

I have a working tooltip jQuery script:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display:none;" class="tooltipcontent">
    <p class="para">Your VIN needs to be:</p>
    <ul class="vinhelp">
        <li>Exactly 17 characters for a vehicle manufactured after 1980 (1981 or later model year.)</li>
        <li>Without the letters I, O, or Q.</li>
    </ul>
</div> <span class="questinfo">test</span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.questinfo').hover(function () {
     // Hover over code

     var title = jQuery('.tooltipcontent').html();

     if (title) {
         jQuery('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
             .html(title)
             .appendTo('body')
             .fadeIn('slow');
     }
 }, function () {
     // Hover out code

     jQuery('.tooltip').remove();
 }).mousemove(function (e) {
     var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
     var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
     jQuery('.tooltip')
         .css({
         top: mousey,
         left: mousex
     })
 });
```

**Working JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/z3cnmf6p/1/

***Note: it is not jquery Ui tooltip.***

**Problem:** This script works fine but my requirement is to bind the hover function to a dynamically created element by jQuery for that purpose I tried jQuery .on() instead of .hover(), but it does not work:

Here is what I have tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/vh5670cy/

Comment: `jQuery('body').on('hover','.questinfo',function () {...` See: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @Moob Yes that is because it is being created using jQuery. line Number 2 here: http://jsfiddle.net/vh5670cy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this http://jsfiddle.net/vp3vqtk8/1/

```
 // creating a new span with class 'questinfo' dynamically.
jQuery("#result").html('<span class="questinfo">Test</span>');

// Binding hover event to the dynamically created span element

$(document).on("mouseenter", '.questinfo', function () {

    var title = jQuery('.tooltipcontent').html();

    if (title.length) {
        jQuery('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
            .html(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    }
}).mousemove(function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
        .css({
        top: mousey,
        left: mousex
    });
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.questinfo', function() {
    $('body').find('.tooltip').remove();
});
```

Comment: Just tried it out the way you suggested, still doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/vp3vqtk8/

Comment: I have a working solution for you , check the updated answer :)

Comment: He just needs position: absolute; to the .tooltip and it will work, cause the .tooltip is getting the values for top and left :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems redundant create `.tooltip` from `.tooltipcontent` - why not just show and hide that? EG: http://jsfiddle.net/vh5670cy/1/

```js
// creating a new span with class 'questinfo' dynamically.
$("#result").html('<span class="questinfo">Test</span>');

// Bind delegated hover events to a parent
$("body")
    .on("mouseover", ".questinfo", function(e){
        $('.tooltip').fadeIn('fast');
    })
    .on("mouseout", ".questinfo", function(e){
        $('.tooltip').hide();
    })
    .on("mousemove", ".questinfo", function(e){
        $('.tooltip').css({
            top: e.pageY + 10,
            left: e.pageX + 10
        })
    });
```

```css
.tooltip {
    background:black;
    padding:15px;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    /* etc */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none;" class="tooltip">
    <p class="para">Your VIN needs to be:</p>
    <ul class="vinhelp">
        <li>Exactly 17 characters for a vehicle manufactured after 1980 (1981 or later model year.)</li>
        <li>Without the letters I, O, or Q.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```